# Pass C# object[] to Matlab Dll method

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, matlab-deployment, variadic-functions

I am trying to pass a C# object array to a Matlab method using parameter array `params` keyword. My Matlab method is complied to a .net assembly Dll. Here is my simple c# method:

```
public void Method1(params object[] objArg)
{           
    _mMExt.mMethod1((MWArray[])objArg);
}
```

I am using `varargin` as input for my Matlab function mMethod1:

```
function mMethod1(varargin)
    nVarargs = length(varargin);
end
```

The issue is when I am converting object[] to MWArray[] by doing this:

```
(MWArray[])objArg
```

It seems that I can use (MWArray)object1 to convert C# object to MWArray, but it doesn't let me to convert an array of object to an array of MWArray.

Is this possible? if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use Linq `objArg.Cast<MWArray>().ToArray()`.

Comment: @juharr - it compiles, but when I pass an integer, it shows the exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is small example I tested.

Say you compiled the following MATLAB function into a .NET assembly using the [*MATLAB Compiler SDK*](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/):

#### myFunction.m

```
function myFunction(varargin)
    for i=1:nargin
        disp(varargin{i});
    end
end
```

Now in your C# program, you can simply call the function `myLib.myClass.myFunction` by passing it a variable number of input arguments like this:

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using myLib;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("calling myFunction(varargin)...");
        CallMyFunction(1, 2.0f, 3.14, "str4");
    }

    static void CallMyFunction(params MWArray[] varargin)  // or object[]
    {
        myClass obj = new myClass();
        obj.myFunction(varargin);
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to explicitly writing:

```
MWArray[] varargin = new MWArray[4];
varargin[0] = new MWNumericArray(1);
varargin[1] = new MWNumericArray(2.0f);
varargin[2] = new MWNumericArray(3.14);
varargin[3] = new MWCharArray("str4");

myClass obj = new myClass();
obj.myFunction(varargin);
```

Comment: Yes, I got confused with what suggested here (http://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/dotnet/code-variable-length-inputs-and-outputs-for-net-client.html). Thank you. So, the issue is object[] that has to be MWArray[]. How do you suggest that it can be object[]?

Comment: in my case (R2016a) both `MWArray[]` and `object[]` worked. Actually inspecting the assembly in the Object Browser, the signature of the generated function is `public void myFunction(params object[] varargin)`

Comment: I am using R2016a too, but mine shows `params MWArray[] varargin`. Do you know what can be the reason of this change?

Comment: ah I see it now. There's actually two assemblies generated  `myLib.dll` and `myLibNative.dll`. I added a reference to the latter. The former one has a signature like you said... For what it's worth, here is the proper documentation page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/data-conversion-between-net-and-matlab.html#bsoy3us-4. Also take note of the project's target framework (.NET version).