# Passing a .Net object by reference to a DLL created in Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

**TDLR**

After researching and testing this problem more (see the update below), I reached this answer:

What I need is to actually pass an object by reference to a DLL created with Matlab using the type-safe API, but this does not seem to be possible. Correct?

I suspect that this is the direct result of them using WCF to facilitate interprocess behind the scenes as mentioned [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/06/03/introducing-type-safe-apis-with-builder-ne/). The fact that it is a DLL (which essentially handles the communication) confused me very much.

So is there a quick way to achieve this (e.g. COM objects come to mind, but I have not worked with them before)?

**/TDLR**

I am trying to figure out how to pass a .Net object to a Matlab method and then call a method on that object. In my Matlab Code I have something like this:

```
DOTNET_object = DOTNET_classFactory.GetStage();
CallDOTNET_class_method_DoSomething(DOTNET_object);
```

Where `DOTNET_classFactory` and `DOTNET_object` are both instances of .Net classes and `CallDOTNET_class_method_DoSomething` would be a Matlab function defined like this:

```
function CallDOTNET_class_method_DoSomething(DOTNET_object)
    DOTNET_object.DoSomething();
end
```

I now need to perform the same two lines above in from within C#, after creating a DLL with the function `CallDOTNET_class_method_DoSomething`. However I am unable to figure out how to pass `DOTNET_object` to my function in the C# code. Here is what I have:

```
Class1 = new Class1();
Class1.CallDOTNET_class_method_DoSomething((MWArray) DOTNET_object);
```

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608175/pass-c-sharp-object-to-matlab-dll-method) , but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go. Would I have to package all the .Net objects (I will need to pass a total of 3 objects) I want to pass to my Matlab function inside an object-array and that unpack the within or is there a more elegant way, where I can pass the three objects separately and explicitely?

**Update:**

As explained here [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/06/03/introducing-type-safe-apis-with-builder-ne/) I have now tried using the type-safe API in Matlab and by creating an interface to define the arguments of `function CallDOTNET_class_method_DoSomething(DOTNET_object)`. I have been able to compile it in Visual Studio. Unfortunately, when I run the it I get the following exception:

> Result StackTrace:
>
> at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray.ConvertObjectToMWArray(Object objIn)
>
> at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.UnpackArgArray(Object[] argArray, Object[] varArgArray)
>
> at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.EvaluateFunctionForTypeSafeCall(String functionName, Int32 numArgsOut, Object[]& argsOut, Object[] argsIn, Object[] varArgsIn)
>
> ...
>
> ... removed, because it is confidential
>
> ...
>
> Result Message:   System.IO.InvalidDataException : Input data type unsupported by MATLAB .NET Assembly

From the message I deduce, that my endeavor is in vain and that you cannot pass anything other than primitive/value types (by that I mean, int, double, bool, etc.) to a Matlab DLL as written here [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-net-data-in-matlab_bte9owt-1.html#bte9pa3-1)?

> Result Message:    System.IO.InvalidDataException : Input data type unsupported by MATLAB .NET Assembly

Am I correct in that assumption or is there any workaround?! In other words/another aspect: What I need is to actually pass an object by reference to the DLL created with Matlab and this does not seem to be possible. Correct?